# Dynamic data allocation looping stopped at line 34 (MS-Excel-VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

I have a data allocation which allocates data based on user selection. 
This code works but the data allocation stops at line 34.

Have tried changing the "TRY" value to 1000 so that it will generate more data but still stops at line 34.

There's no error prompting and the code still works but data allocation stops at line 34 and deletes the data afetrwards.

Here's my codes:

```
Sub MapTIX()
    Dim YRTCounter As Long, TRYCounter As Long, YRT As Long, TRY As Long
    Dim nextrow As Long
    Dim dummy As String
    Dim StartQ As String

    StartQ = ActiveSheet.Range("K7").Value
    YRT = ActiveSheet.Range("B4").Value
    TRY = ActiveSheet.Range("F4").Value
    nextrow = ActiveSheet.Range("O4").Value + 3
    YRTCounter = 4
    TRYCounter = 4

    If StartQ = "YRT" Then
       If YRT >= TRY Then
          YRT_YRTTRY_TIX
       Else
          YRT_TRYYRT_TIX
       End If
    End If

    If StartQ = "TRY" Then
        If YRT <= TRY Then
          TRY_TRYYRT_TIX
        Else
           TRY_YRTTRY_TIX
        End If
    End If

End Sub

Sub YRT_YRTTRY_TIX()
    Dim YRTCounter As Long, TRYCounter As Long, YRT As Long, TRY As Long
    Dim nextrow As Long
    Dim dummy As String

    YRT = ActiveSheet.Range("B4").Value + 3
    TRY = ActiveSheet.Range("F4").Value + 3
    nextrow = ActiveSheet.Range("O4").Value + 4
    YRTCounter = 4
    TRYCounter = 4
    nexc = 4

    For YRTCounter = 4 To YRT
       ActiveSheet.Range("Q" & nextrow).Value = ActiveSheet.Range("D" & YRTCounter).Value
       ActiveSheet.Range("V" & nextrow).Value = ActiveSheet.Range("D28").Value
       nextrow = ActiveSheet.Range("O4").Value + 4
       ActiveSheet.Range("Q" & nextrow).Value = ActiveSheet.Range("H" & TRYCounter).Value
       ActiveSheet.Range("V" & nextrow).Value = ActiveSheet.Range("D28").Value
       TRYCounter = TRYCounter + 1
       nextrow = ActiveSheet.Range("O4").Value + 4
    Next YRTCounter

End Sub
```

.

```
Sub YRT_TRYYRT_TIX()
    Dim YRTCounter As Long, TRYCounter As Long, YRT As Long, TRY As Long
    Dim nextrow As Long
    Dim dummy As String

    YRT = ActiveSheet.Range("B4").Value + 3
    TRY = ActiveSheet.Range("F4").Value + 3
    nextrow = ActiveSheet.Range("O4").Value + 4
    YRTCounter = 4
    TRYCounter = 4

    For TRYCounter = 4 To TRY
        ActiveSheet.Range("Q" & nextrow).Value = ActiveSheet.Range("D" & YRTCounter).Value
        ActiveSheet.Range("V" & nextrow).Value = ActiveSheet.Range("D28").Value
        nextrow = ActiveSheet.Range("O4").Value + 4
        ActiveSheet.Range("Q" & nextrow).Value = ActiveSheet.Range("H" & TRYCounter).Value
        ActiveSheet.Range("V" & nextrow).Value = ActiveSheet.Range("D28").Value
        YRTCounter = YRTCounter + 1
        nextrow = ActiveSheet.Range("O4").Value + 4
    Next TRYCounter
End Sub

Sub TRY_YRTTRY_TIX()
    Dim YRTCounter As Long, TRYCounter As Long, YRT As Long, TRY As Long
    Dim nextrow As Long
    Dim dummy As String

    YRT = ActiveSheet.Range("B4").Value + 3
    TRY = ActiveSheet.Range("F4").Value + 3
    nextrow = ActiveSheet.Range("O4").Value + 4
    YRTCounter = 4
    TRYCounter = 4

    For YRTCounter = 4 To YRT
        ActiveSheet.Range("Q" & nextrow).Value = ActiveSheet.Range("H" & TRYCounter).Value
        ActiveSheet.Range("V" & nextrow).Value = ActiveSheet.Range("D28").Value
        nextrow = ActiveSheet.Range("O4").Value + 4
        ActiveSheet.Range("Q" & nextrow).Value = ActiveSheet.Range("D" & YRTCounter).Value
        ActiveSheet.Range("V" & nextrow).Value = ActiveSheet.Range("D28").Value
        TRYCounter = TRYCounter + 1
        nextrow = ActiveSheet.Range("O4").Value + 4
    Next YRTCounter
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Increasing `MaxCase` will not do anything in that code.

I am assuming the value in the cell below is 31. Adding 3 to the end is why you loop ends at row 34

```
YRT = ActiveSheet.Range("B4").Value + 3
```

Try increasing the value in `ActiveSheet.Range("B4")` to see if your loop will go further.

Comment: Have increased the value from 3 to 20 still limits to line 34. The data count on Cell "B4" is the count of user data.

Comment: Try changing `ActiveSheet.Range("F4")` to see if that works? Each method is using a different cell value.

Comment: Its the same with `ActiveSheet.Range("B4")` both are counted values of the user data input while `ActiveSheet.Range("O4")` are counted data of the allocated user data input

Comment: What line exactly is not doing what you want? And why do you have a variable called `MaxCase` when it is not declared in these methods?

Comment: I removed `MaxCase` since it wasn't declared. Have tried changing numbers such the `YRT = ActiveSheet.Range("B4").Value + 3` but still loops end in line 34.

Comment: Well, you have to look at the code. The loop's end is governed by the value of the variables `YRT` and `TRY`, so if it is stopping at 34 you need to look at that value. BTW , if you are using `YRTCounter` and `TRYCounter` as an interger in a for loop, you do not need to declare them. Also, `nextrow` is not being incremented in this code.

Comment: still not working even if I changed from `For TRYCounter = 4 To TRY` to `For TRYCounter = 4 To 1000`

Comment: OK, try this on all of your loops, replace `nextrow = ActiveSheet.Range("O4").Value + 4` with  `nextrow = TRYCounter + ActiveSheet.Range("O4").Value`